# Azure + IE11 502 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, azure, internet-explorer-11

I ve hosted my asp.net MVC website in Azure. I am redirecting from the first page to the second via javascript and the url is like http://mywebsite.net/Home/Method/?value=someValueWithGreekCharacters

When I am trying it with firefox or chrome everything works fine.When I am trying it with IE11 i got this error message :

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the         

Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it   

 received an invalid response from the content server.
```

When I m trying to run the website localy with VS2012 everything works fine with all browsers.

Also if I change the value in the url from greek characters to english there is no error in IE11 (but also no proper results).

I conclude that it has to be something with the combination of azure+ie11+greek characters in query string.
Is it a known bug?Any ideas?

Thanx in advance!